# If $S$ is a group and $a^{-1} = a$ for all $a\in S$, the group is commutative.

Tags: group-theory

> Show that if $(S, \ast)$ is a group, and $a^{-1} = a$ for all $a\in S$, the group is commutative.

I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Hint: $(ab)^{-1} = $?

Comment: Let $a,\, b \in S$. What is $(ab)^{-1}$?

Answer (score 3):

HINT: In any group you have $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$. In **this** group it’s also equal to ... ? And $b^{-1}a^{-1}$ simplifies to ... ?

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain what it is that the upvoters and I all missed?

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall a\in G, a^{-1}=a\longrightarrow a^2=1\Longrightarrow\forall a,b\in G, a^2=b^2=1,(ab)^2=1$$
$$\Longrightarrow(ab)^2=1=a^2b^2\longrightarrow abab=aabb\Longrightarrow ab=ba$$